# Rails+mongoid: update_all("position=position-1")?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, increment

Is this possible with Rails+Mongoid:

```
Model.update_all("position=position-1")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there's no direct equivalent to this idiom (set field to a some function of some fields of the document), there is a way to do this exact update.

```
Model.collection.update({},  # find all documents
                        {'$inc' => {:position => -1}}, # decrement position
                        :multi => true) # multi-update (update all)
```

This is using underlying mongodb driver to do the job. I don't know how to express this in Mongoid interface.

Comment: Doesn't always work. It says the update method should have 3 params only.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that was half ruby, half javascript. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can!
Without selection (update all collections):

```
Model.update_all(obsolete: false)
```

or with selection:

```
Model.where(:id.in => ids_array).update_all(obsolete: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
Model.all.inc(:position, -1)
```